# Paradox ? I never understand this clearly

Tags: meaning, appropriate

The sentence:

I want to finish this game but wish it never ends.

Also if possible can you explain what makes a sentence a paradox exactly ?

Comment: What do you wish to know that a dictionary doesn't explain?

Comment: If you finish it, the game will end. If it never ends, you can not finish it. It is impossible for the game to be both endless and winnable.

Comment: @SrJoven: From the dictionary "A paradox is a statement that apparently contradicts itself and yet might be true" taking this into consideration, the first half is what is considered true and the second half contradicts it, so that makes it a paradox I guess ?

Comment: There are multiple dictionaries available, as well as [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradox). The order of which part is true or which is not is not relevant. The paradox is more, generally stated, about recursion (as an example): a statement that seems false, but may be true, but if it's true, then the statement can't be valid. Consider "This statement is false."

Answer (score 0):

This is an *[approach-avoidance conflict](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approach-avoidance_conflict)*

> Approach-avoidance conflicts occur when there is one goal or event that has both positive and negative effects or characteristics that make the goal appealing and unappealing simultaneously. [*Wikipedia*]

It [hurts so good](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/johncougarmellencamp/hurtssogood.html).

Comment: I really don't see how this answers the question. Someone taking pleasure from being hurt is no more different than someone taking pleasure from eating spicy food (and indeed it is what's actually happening). I don't see a paradox there so it doesn't give am example either

Answer (score 0):

The difficulty with English usage of *paradox* is that valid definitions of the term lead to inconsistent conclusions about whether a particular thing is or is not a paradox: A statement may constitute a paradox under one valid definition of the term, but not under another valid definition.

First let's take a look at the definitions of the word that appear in Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary (2003):

> **paradox** *n* (1540) **1 :** a tenet contrary to received opinion **2 a :** a statement that is seemingly contradictory or opposed to common sense and yet is perhaps true **b :** a self-contradictory statement that at first seems true **c :** an argument that apparently derives self-contradictory conclusions by valid deduction from acceptable premises **3 :** one (as a person, situation, or action) having seemingly contradictory qualities or phases

The statement "I want to win this game, but at the same time I don't want this game to ever end," it seems to me, does not express a paradox in the sense of definition **1** (a contrary tenet), **2(b)** (an untrue statement that at first seems true), **2(c)** (a statement that makes an inherently contradictory logical argument), or **3** (a paradoxical person, situation, or action, not a paradoxical statement). Instead, it expresses contradictory yet true feelings that a person might experience simultaneously.

But arguably the example does qualify as paradox under the Eleventh Collegiate's definition **2(a)**:

> a statement that is seemingly contradictory or opposed to common sense and yet is perhaps true

So, paradoxically, the example you give both is and isn't a paradox.